# Showing the X and Y axes and changing their range with spplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to use the spplot function in R in plot spatial data. While my plots look fine by my standards, I'm trying to figure out how to change the range of my visualizations and display their X and Y axes.

I'm currently using the spplot function like so:

```
 spplot(no2_surf.idw['var1.pred'],main = 'interpolated no2 surface concentrations',ylim<- c(latv[200],latv[40]), xlim <- c(lonv[60],lonv[180]))
```

Using xlim and ylim to specify the range of my output, but it isn't changing my plotted output at all.

I also have no clue how to show the axes on the displayed graph.

The following is a graph of my output, which I intend to zoom into a city with.
[image]

The following is my code to display the output.

```
 spplot(no2_surf.idw['var1.pred'],main = 'interpolated no2 surface concentrations',ylim<- c(latv[200],latv[40]), xlim <- c(lonv[60],lonv[180]))
```

Currently, I'm not getting any "Zooming" from my code.

Comment: Use `xlim = ` instead of `xlim <- `

Comment: @jtr13 Thanks! Worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jtr13 helped answer this! Needed to use an equal symbol instead of an arrow. Thanks @jtr13!